# Updating tkinter window from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a piece of code that does some textual analysis and displays the results in a tkinter window. 
Since users can choose to do the same analysis on multiple sources, and this can take quite some time, I would like to display the results as they become available.
However, the tkinter window pops up only after the last result becomes available. From other questions on Stackoverflow, I understand why this does not work (simplified version of my code):

```
class Output:
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_main_variables()

    def set_main_variables(self):
        self.names= []
        #and other variables...

    def initialize(self):
        self.t = Tk()
        self.make_frames()
        self.populate_frames()
        self.t.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        self.populate_frames()

    def populate_frames(self):
        <uses the data in self.names to display the results>

output = Output()
for i, s in enumerate(sources):
    results = analyze(s)
    output.names = results
    if i == 0:
        output.initialize()
    else:
        output.update()
```

Therefore, I tried taking the initialize() out of the loop, and creating a button in the window by which the user can update the results (if any are available):

```
output = Output()
first_results = analyze(s[0])
output.names = first_results
output.initialize()

for i, s in enumerate(sources):
    results = analyze(s)
    output.names = results
```

This does not solve the problem, though; the window still pops up only after the last source has been analyzed.

I have read many possible options to deal with this (using after, guiloop, etc.) but I don't see how these could help me in this situation.

Could anyone set me on the right path?

Comment: What you want is calling your function analyze in a function that is called inside an `after` call. And you will probably need `update_idletasks` too.

Comment: Hi Eric, the problem is that the analyze function is already called by another function. So would you suggest to call Output first, and then call analyze from within output? I thought about that, but I'm trying to keep the logic of my program separated from the GUI as much as possible.

Comment: Which function? Can you please fix your indentation?

Comment: Hi Eric, I fixed the indentation. I mean, in my real code (not the simplified version above)  the loop in which the analyze function is called, is part of a function that is called from a separate module.

Comment: Sorry, I was half-wrong. You should call `self.t.update_idletasks()` at the end of `populate_frames` if you want the tkinter window to update on each result. (If you want the window to stay responsive, you need threads, I think)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in answering my question, Eric, but the problem persists: with your solution, the window does open after the first iteration, but it is entirely blank; the data is still only displayed at the end of the loop.

Comment: Please post your current code at the end of your question...

Answer (score 0):

A colleague found the solution to my question.

Eric, in the comments, put me partly on the right path. He proposed using update_idletasks() in the GUI, but that did not work: it opened a blank window, which was filled in with widgets only when the "sources" loop was finished. 
The solution was to put update() not inside the GUI, but inside the loop that is sending the updates to the GUI. 
A simplified example with working code:

```
from tkinter import *

class SimpleTestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
        self.top = Tk()
        self.names_string = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(self.top, textvar=self.names_string).pack()
        #self.top.mainloop()

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.names_string.set("\n".join(self.names))


def test(gui):
    names = ["a", "b", "c"]
    sources = [11, 2, 3]
    for i, s in enumerate(sources):
        print(i)
        gui.names.append(names[i])
        print(gui.names)
        gui.updateLabel()
        gui.top.update()
        #gui.top.update_idletasks() 
        time.sleep(3) # this simulates the program taking /
                      # some time to do its analysis of the source

s = SimpleTestClass()
test(s)
```

Two notes:

- using update_idletasks() works as well, but displays a strange black
  border at the bottom of the window until the sources loop is
  finished.
- calling self.top.mainloop() blocks the window update

I also tried an alternative version, where the user can push a button to manually update the list of results, but this did not function well (the button reacts only when the sources loop is finished):

```
class SimpleTestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
        self.top = Tk()
        self.names_string = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(self.top, textvar=self.names_string).pack()
        Button(self.top, text="update", command=self.updateLabel).pack()

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.names_string.set("\n".join(self.names))


def test(gui):
    names = ["a", "b", "c"]
    sources = [11, 2, 3]
    for i, s in enumerate(sources):
        gui.names.append(names[i])
        print(gui.names)
        gui.top.update()
        time.sleep(3) # this simulates the program taking /
                      # some time to do its analysis of the source

s = SimpleTestClass()
test(s)
```